# Change Background color (css property) using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to Change the background colour on click . This is my code work that i tried.pls help me out :)

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready(function(){

$(#co).click(change()
{
$(body).css("background-color":"blue");
});
});
```

**Css code**

```
body
{
background-color:red;
}
```

**Body code**

```
      <body>

    <div id="co" click="change()">

hello

    </div>
```

Answer (score 27):

You're using a colon instead of a comma. Try:

```
$(body).css("background-color","blue");
```

You also need to wrap the id in quotes or it will look for a variable called `#co`

```
$("#co").click(change()
```

There are many more issues here. `click` isn't an HTML attribute. You want `onclick` (which is redundant). Try this:

```
<div id="co"> <!-- no onclick method needed -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#co").click(function() {
        $("body").css("background-color","blue"); //edit, body must be in quotes!
    });
});
</script>
```

You were trying to call an undefined method. It looks like you were trying to declare it inside the callback statement? I'm not sure. But please compare this to your code and see the differences.

http://jsfiddle.net/CLwE5/ demo fiddle

Comment: Taking a second look.. there are issues everywhere in your code. I will update my answer

Comment: Cannot edit the valid solution gived by RUJordan, it only need to close the script tag...

Comment: @SunnyCoder be more specific. What does the error console say? Not working doens't tell me much

Comment: Found it. body needs to be in quotes. See my edit, I included a working demo

Comment: @SunnyCoder because jQuery is handling the click event. So if you added the onclick back, it would be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("body").css({"background-color":"blue"});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#co").click(function(){
   $(this).css({"backgroundColor" : "blue"});
});
```

Comment: please describe your answer so it'll make sense for all user.

Comment: what do you mean? when user clicks on the id named  "co" the background color of that changes to blue!

Comment: Totally agrees with you but for new user or fresher who don't know anything about css or jquery for them need description. Hope this make sense.

Comment: mmm... you're right but this user used jquery in the code. means he/she knows something about that :)

Answer (score 1):

The code below will change the div to blue.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#co").click({
            $("body").css("background-color","blue");
      });
    }); 
</script>
<body>
      <div id="co">hello</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around `#co`

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove `onclick` method from `div` element

2.Remove function `change()` from jQuery code and in place of that create an anonymous function like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $('#co').click(function()
   {

  $('body').css('background-color','blue');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bchange").click(function() {
    $("body, this").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Comment: Your answer is under review for being a low quality answer. Please provide an explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change **[Background Color](https://htmlunderline.com/css-background-color/)** using on click button **jquery**

Below is the code of jquery, which you can put in your head tag.

jQuery Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").addClass("myclass");
      });
    });
</script>
```

CSS Code:

```
<style>
    .myclass {
        background-color: red;
        padding: 100px;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    <button>Click Here</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Your profile indicates you're associated with the company that owns the site to which you have linked. Linking to something you're affiliated with (e.g. a product or website) without disclosing it's yours *in your post* is considered spam on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Answer (score 0):

Try below jQuery snippet, you can change color :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#co").click(function() {
            $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#co").click(function() {
        $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="co" click="change()">hello</div>
```